# Why the object pose in render output is different from viewport?

Tags: pose-mode

Why the pose I set up in the viewport are not being rendered in the output?
If I open and close the doors, they don't get to the render output. Not even rotating the object will be reflected in the output.
I have also set the animation to 0 frames.
And yet it's not working and it completely ignores the animation pose I set up.

[image]

Comment: when you choose a new pose, are you at least keyframing the new pose?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found the answer: had to eliminate all the animation tracks that were inside the object (it was an exported object).